# How to resolve external symbols in dll at run time, instead of link time with Cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin, shared-libraries, ld, undefined-symbol

I am porting a set of programs from linux to Windows+Cygwin. The main shared library of the set refers to a few constant external symbols declared in the programs using the shared library. I didn't find the way to do the same thing with Cygwin. ld complaints about unresolved symbols when building the shared library. Is the option --allow-shlib-undefined unsupported on Windows+Cygwin ?

Example :

mydll.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern const int a;

void f(void)
{
  printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

myprog.c

```
const int a = 1;

extern void f(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  f();
}
```

Command used to build the dll :

```
 gcc -shared -o libmydll.so -Xlinker --allow-shlib-undefined mydll.c
```

Comment: Please add the command to build the dll

Comment: Command added to the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Not simple as circular dependency are a mess under Windows

https://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html#wincircular

Workaround:

```
$ ar sqc  libmyprog.dll.a myprog.o
$ gcc --shared mydll.o -Wl,--out-implib=libmydll.dll.a -Wl,--export-all-symbols -o mydll.dll -L. -lmyprog
$ gcc myprog.o -Wl,--out-implib=libmyprog.dll.a -Wl,--export-all-symbols  -o myprog.exe -L. -lmydll
$ gcc --shared mydll.o -Wl,--out-implib=libmydll.dll.a -Wl,--export-all-symbols -o mydll.dll -L. -lmyprog
$ ./myprog.exe
1
```

To verify that they are cross dependent:

```
$ objdump.exe -x mydll.dll  | grep "DLL Name"
        DLL Name: myprog.exe
        DLL Name: cygwin1.dll
        DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll

$ objdump.exe -x myprog.exe  | grep "DLL Name"
        DLL Name: mydll.dll
        DLL Name: cygwin1.dll
        DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for this workaround. I will try to extend it to my real case : a dll made of a lot of object files and a lot of programs linked to the dll. As far as I understand, it could be necessary to create a dll per program.

Comment: use comments, not answers for your replies. Are the data always the same for all programs ?

Comment: No, If the data were the same, I would have created the constants in the dll. I rewrote a part of the main dll (a runtime library) and of the program generator (a translator from a Basic language to C++) to fix dynamically the values of several constants just at the beginning of main(). However, there are still 2 non critical constants impossible to set dynamically because they are used in constructors of global variables. Each constant cant take two values, 0 or 1. Either I create a set of dlls for all 4 possible combinations, or I force the constants to their less restricting values.